# How to set the default delay for frames when animating?

Tags: gimp

I imported a bunch of frames as layers and did Filters → Animation → Optimize (for GIF). I got the layers transformed and delay applied to each layer’s name. In my case it is "(100ms)". But I’d wanted this delay to be 50ms, so I could then set specific delay for some frames manually.

Answer (score 8):

You can specify a default delay upon export of your gif.

Since this is a bit more tricky here is what you do, to **reset all delays on each layer**:

1. Export your animation as a GIF. In the GIF Export Dialog, set the
   `Delay between frames where unspecified` to `50ms` and export it to
   `<yourname>.gif`, e.g. `test.gif`.
2. Tick the checkbox below labeled: `Use delay entered above for all
   frames`. This will reset the delay on all layers to `50ms`.
3. Import your GIF again. All layers should now state the `50ms` delay. You can now set the custom delay on specific layers. Export the GIF again by using **Export...**.
4. **Make sure you untick previous settings.** This time you don't set anything and export it with the default settings.

Any additional details, are described [in the documentation under File Formats](http://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-images-out.html#gimp-using-fileformats-export-dialog).

Comment: Okay, you have 150 frames which GIMP marked as 100ms. You need all them to have a 50ms delay except the last one which must have 2000ms. Try to do that in export menu.

Comment: You will need to get rid of the optimisation, either by importing your frames as layers again or programmatically remove the delay in the layer name. Afterwards to can provide the non-default delay and use the export dialog.

Comment: "programmatically"?

Comment: "programmatically" meaning by using a script written in a programming language to "unset" all delays in the layer names.

Comment: Or answer or move that question to StackOverflow then